# javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [sitemesh]: could not be initialized when deploying grails 2.11 app to WebSphere 8.5 liberty profile?

Tags: grails, websphere, websphere-liberty

When I try and deploy my grails application to a WebSphere 8.5 liberty profile server I get the following error message.

```
Error Message: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [sitemesh]: could not be initialized
```

I've set up a parent last class loading policy for my application. The same war file deploys with no problems to tomcat located on the same server. Any ideas of what could be causing this and how to work around it? I've pasted the full stacktrace below.

```
Error Page Exception
SRVE0260E: The server cannot use the error page specified for your application to handle the Original Exception printed below.


Original Exception: 
Error Message: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [sitemesh]: could not be initialized
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor
Error Stack: 
com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.FactoryException: Could not initialize DecoratorMapper : org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsLayoutDecoratorMapper: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'groovyPageLayoutFinder' is defined 
     at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.BaseFactory.pushDecoratorMapper(BaseFactory.java:117) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.Grails5535Factory.loadDecoratorMappers(Grails5535Factory.java:231) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.Grails5535Factory.loadConfig(Grails5535Factory.java:98) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.Grails5535Factory.(Grails5535Factory.java:66) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.init(GrailsPageFilter.java:83) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:142) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:579) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:480) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:299) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:372) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:903) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1036) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4173) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:302) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:296) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1006) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$1.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:253) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:457) 
     at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:398) 
     at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:380) 
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) 
     Root cause: 
     org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'groovyPageLayoutFinder' is defined 
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:553) 
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1095) 
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:277) 
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) 
     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1102) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsLayoutDecoratorMapper.init(GrailsLayoutDecoratorMapper.java:48) 
     at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.BaseFactory.pushDecoratorMapper(BaseFactory.java:110) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.Grails5535Factory.loadDecoratorMappers(Grails5535Factory.java:231) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.Grails5535Factory.loadConfig(Grails5535Factory.java:98) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.Grails5535Factory.(Grails5535Factory.java:66) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.init(GrailsPageFilter.java:83) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:142) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:579) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:480) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:299) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:372) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:903) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1036) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4173) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:302) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:296) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1006) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$1.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:253) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:457) 
     at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:398) 
     at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:380) 
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) 




Error Page Exception: 
Error Message: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [sitemesh]: could not be initialized
Error Code: 0
Target Servlet: 
Error Stack: 
com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.FactoryException: Could not initialize DecoratorMapper : org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsLayoutDecoratorMapper: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'groovyPageLayoutFinder' is defined 
     at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.BaseFactory.pushDecoratorMapper(BaseFactory.java:117) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.Grails5535Factory.loadDecoratorMappers(Grails5535Factory.java:231) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.Grails5535Factory.loadConfig(Grails5535Factory.java:98) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.Grails5535Factory.(Grails5535Factory.java:66) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.init(GrailsPageFilter.java:83) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:142) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:579) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:480) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:299) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:372) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:906) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1036) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1383) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:191) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.sendError(WebApp.java:3650) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleException(WebApp.java:4203) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4184) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:302) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:296) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1006) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$1.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:253) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:457) 
     at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:398) 
     at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:380) 
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) 
     Root cause: 
     org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'groovyPageLayoutFinder' is defined 
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:553) 
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1095) 
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:277) 
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) 
     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1102) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsLayoutDecoratorMapper.init(GrailsLayoutDecoratorMapper.java:48) 
     at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.factory.BaseFactory.pushDecoratorMapper(BaseFactory.java:110) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.Grails5535Factory.loadDecoratorMappers(Grails5535Factory.java:231) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.Grails5535Factory.loadConfig(Grails5535Factory.java:98) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.Grails5535Factory.(Grails5535Factory.java:66) 
     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.init(GrailsPageFilter.java:83) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:142) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:579) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:480) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:299) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:372) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:906) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1036) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1383) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:191) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.sendError(WebApp.java:3650) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleException(WebApp.java:4203) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4184) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:302) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:296) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1006) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$1.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:253) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:457) 
     at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:398) 
     at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:380) 
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: What caused you to need the parent-last class loading policy?  Also, have you successfully deployed any other Grails applications to WAS Liberty?

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere 8.5 Liberty Profile does not expand WARs upon deployment, and surprisingly quite a few web applications heavily depend on the feature. That's what has led to your case.

I'm pretty sure you deployed the Grails web application as a WAR.

The solution is quite simple - deploy the web application expanded and the issue goes away.

To prove my thought I ran the sample from [2.3 Creating an Application](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html#creatingAnApplication). When I deployed it, the error message you faced was indeed displayed in the browser and the logs.

```
jacek:~/sandbox/helloworld
$ cp target/helloworld-0.1.war ~/apps/wlp/usr/servers/libertyGrails/dropins/
```

What you overlooked though was the line in the logs when it asked whether the web archive is expanded.

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/grails-app/i18n/messages.properties] cannot be resolved to
>   absolute file path - web application archive not expanded?    ... 20
>   more

I redeployed the web application (a mere `rm` with `unzip -d` afterwards), and the welcome page displayed properly.

```
jacek:~/sandbox/helloworld
$ rm ~/apps/wlp/usr/servers/libertyGrails/dropins/helloworld-0.1.war
jacek:~/sandbox/helloworld
$ unzip -d ~/apps/wlp/usr/servers/libertyGrails/dropins/helloworld-0.1.war target/helloworld-0.1.war
jacek:~/sandbox/helloworld
$ open http://localhost:9080/helloworld-0.1
```